# Which distribution Should I use?

Tags: probability

> Erik and Bentz are playing with dice. The two roll a dice and the one who got the higher number win a coin.
>   
>   Let the be random variable $X$ the profit of Erik in 10 games, how does $X$ distribute?

So $p=\frac{15}{36}$ which is same as the sum of all the conditional probability of Erik get a higher number depending on Bentz number.

How much "success" do I need to count?

The Answer is $X\sim B(10,\frac{15}{36})$

Comment: What exactly do you *mean* by the second last sentence ?

Comment: @trueblueanil sorry edited

Comment: Have you not already *quoted* the answer ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't not understand why they chose this distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2$ dice are thrown then the probability that die1 will show the same face as die2 is $\frac16$.

So the probability that they show unequal faces is $1-\frac16=\frac56$.

The probability that die1 shows a higher number than die2 equals the probability that die2 shows a higher number than die1.

Consequently the probability that die1 shows a higher number than die2 is $\frac12\frac56=\frac5{12}$.

Let's say that die1 is the die of Eric.

There are $10$ independent rounds and in each of them there is chance of $\frac5{12}$ on success.

So indeed binomial distribution with parameters $n=10$ and $p=\frac5{12}$.

Comment: In case I will need to count $X<5$ for example, I will need to sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{4} (\frac{5}{12} )^n*(\frac{5}{12})^{1-n}$$ ?

Comment: $P\left(X<5\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{4}\binom{10}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{10-k}$
where $p=\frac{5}{12}$. See [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

i think, since these ten games are independent, the X will be binomial

Answer (score 1):

When 2 people roll a dice, there are **$6\times 6 = 36$** possible outcomes, out of which 6 will have identical faces, and Eric will win in half of the remaining 30, thus P(win) = **15/36**

You have already quoted the answer to "Which distribution should I use?"

Note that it will not give Eric wins vs Benz wins, it is Eric wins vs Eric does *not* win